# dojo, filteringselect, query and exclude string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a little problem.

I have a filteringSelect and I want to exclude from the choices those which have a specific value (price equal to 50).

So here is my code which didn't work (the select becomes empty) :

```
priceSelect.query.price = "^(?!50)$"
```

Well, I think my regex is good but if it's not working it is not valid.

Comment: Providing some input sample could **MAYBE** increase the possibility that you actually get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex will only match the empty string, exactly as if you would have used `^$`. The negative lookahead is just looking ahead if there is not those two digits, but it is not matching anything.

So you will need additionally a part that is matching the input, something like this:

```
priceSelect.query.price = "^(?!50$)\d+$"
```

I also added the `$` into your lookahead, otherwise it will reject every number that starts with "50" (e.g. 500, 509, ...)

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v70v)